# How to set default value for dropdown menu on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have following code

```
        <select name="status_drop" id="status" selected="<%=session[:status]%>" >
            <option value="0">Completed</option>
            <option value="1">Not Completed</option>
        </select>
```

I have session call **session[:status]** it hold either 1 or 0 and I need to set default value according to the **session[:status]** value. Please can some one help on this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that

```
<select name="status_drop" id="status">
    <option value="0"<%= ' selected="selected"' if session[:status] == 0 %>>Completed</option>
    <option value="1"<%= ' selected="selected"' if session[:status] == 1 %>>Not Completed</option>
 </select>
```